# how do you enable bash completion for a bash script

Tags: bash

I would like to create a bash script foo.sh.

When it runs, it will prompt for a directory.  The user will be able to use tab to auto complete?

Here is some example code assuming read has some option.

```
echo -n "Enter the directory of awesomeness: "
read --enable-autocomplete DIR_OF_AWESOMENESS
echo "The Dir of Awesomeness is $DIR_OF_AWESOMENESS"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash auto-completion works on command-line arguments. Here is [a two-part introduction for writing auto-completion](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2) with examples.